# How can I handle arrow keys in a Perl script under cygwin?

Tags: windows, perl, cygwin

I am running Perl script under cygwin which takes input from `<STDIN>` and process the requests continuously.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Enter Input:";
while(<STDIN>) {
    print "Recieved Input: $_";
    print "Enter Input:";
}



    $perl testPerl.pl        
    Enter input:input1
    Recieved input:input1
    Enter input:inpt2
    Recieved input:input2
    Enter input:
```

Now, I would like the up arrow at the current prompt: "Enter input:" to take the previous inputs i.e "input2","input1"

It behaves as expected when running under windows enivronment (cmd.exe)
But the problem under cygwin is that the up arrow literally takes the cursor 1 row up  i.e it takes to the line "Recieved input:input2"

Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: Please share the code that you are using to process the keystrokes. Also, you may want to rephrase your post so that it contains a clear question.

Comment: Thanks Ether for the comment. I have attached the code snippet and rephrased the question to be more clear. I am not using any special routines to process the keystrokes, its just capturing the standard input <STDIN>. Please let me know if any information is required further.

Comment: This is a terminal configuration issue, I think. I've always hated the terminals that cygwin provides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the Term::Readline module. This will take over input for your program, and handles history, which is what I think you're talking about.

This would be a direct translation of your program to using Term::ReadLine:

```
 use Term::ReadLine;
 my $term = new Term::ReadLine 'Simple Perl calc';
 my $prompt = "Enter Input: ";
 while ( defined ($_ = $term->readline($prompt)) ) {
   print "Recieved Input:$_\n";
   $term->addhistory($_) if /\S/;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a big difference in the handling of the command line history between the Windows console and Unix terminals. On Windows, it's done by the console, whereas on Unix, applications are responsible for it. I don't know anything about Perl, but you'll need to use something like the readline library. This looks helpful: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html

Comment: The readline library and the Perl function of the same name are different beasts.